# Do we need to upgrade a PS/Xbox in the same sense as computers needs to?

Tags: pc, ps3

Like, Graphic cards, hard disk, sound, etc. that we do in PC in order to play newer games?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Apart from the HDD, you can't really upgrade anything (potentially apart from hardcore console modding, but certainly nothing standard). You will need to upgrade *in a way*, but that would be by buying an entirely new console whenever another generation comes out.

For example, many (not all) games that have been released for PS4 are not playable on a PS3, simply due to various hardware limitations (different processor/memory architectures between console generations, faster/better components able to support higher resolutions, etc.). You will need to upgrade. A new graphics card cannot be slapped into a PS3 to improve it.

That said, a game developed for PS3 is expected to run on any type of PS3, regardless of how old the model. A PS3 is always going to be a PS3. Consoles are designed to be more "plug  and play" than PC, but of course you lose that flexibility in your hardware.

Comment: But suppose you do have a PS3, and you have it for like 1 year. Now, a newer games comes out for the same PS3 machine but with better graphics. So, is it playable on the same one year old machine?

Comment: Yes, a PS3 is a PS3, newer iterations might have small tweaks but all games made for a PS3 run on a PS3 (barring, you know, the PS3 being broken)

Comment: @Usernew Yes. Games are developed specifically for certain platforms. You would never make a PS3 game with graphics that it can't handle or calculations that it can't perform. You'll be fine.

Comment: @KevinvanderVelden is completely right. Once the PS3 was developed, every game that has come out since is expected to run on every machine that has been manufactured.

Comment: The answer is useful, but the phrase "simply due to limitations" is not. I suggest this is expanded a bit, e.g. different processor/memory architectures between console generations, faster/better components able to support higher resolutions, etc.

Comment: @Alex, will incorporate that part of your comment into the answer, thanks :)

Comment: @DangerZone Arqade/all SE's have transcended the need for the atrociousness that is "Edit:" by having a full revision history for every question/answer (accessible by clicking "edited X ago").

Comment: Fair point @MrLemon.

Comment: I thought there was an issue with GTA 5 not working properly on the very first copies of the PS3/X360. Am I so mistaken in that?

Comment: Must say, downvote due to phone bug >.< perhaps a mod could undo it for me?

Comment: @Usernew Sometimes consoles will release new models that are still the same "generation". The example that comes to mind is usually PlayStation releases a slimmer version. Microsoft released that slimmer black Xbox 360 with built in wifi. It's possible these newer models have different specs, like more RAM or better graphics card, but there's sort of an unspoken rule that they should all be able to play all games for that "generation" and that all games in that "generation" should be able to be played on all models in the "generation".

Comment: Sometimes there can be an "extra feature", like WiFi, that will be released with newer models. In some cases you can upgrade earlier models with the same feature, but these come as seperate plug in and play packs. While a game released for the console directly always works, you DO have games that wont always work. Earlier PS3 models had backward compatibility IIRC, while newer models removed the feature, as an example.

Comment: and a better TV means better graphics?

Comment: @CaptainMan This is a good thing about Consoles :)

Comment: @Timelord64 Which one is better? Xbox or PS in terms of specs?

Comment: Im not sure @Usernew. Someone else might chime in. Im an xbox fanboy and Od still wager playstation. That said, ps4 released at 60fps, xbox at 30. Xbox is up at 60 now. No idea how that works

Comment: @Timelord64 I favour Xbox for the left analog stick position unlike PS. It is  more comfortable in hands.

Comment: @Usernew actually it'd be beter if consoles *did* allow piece-by-piece upgrading and customization like PC does. You can upgrade as often as you like and still have backwards compatibility with PC.

Answer (score 9):

I like to elaborate on the "hardware design stability" in @DangerZone's answer a bit.

When you want to run a PS3 game, it will run on [any PS3 model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayStation_3_models), regardless whether it's a model from 2006 or 2012. But not only will it run, it will run exactly the same (apart from differences due to different HDD performance). The hardware of a console may change, but the manufacturer (usually) takes care to only do changes that have no effect on compatibility. This means that a program (game) usually does not see any relevant difference between the various models. The only difference is usually HDD performance (for systems that have these).

This stability is an essential property of consoles: game developers can rely on the fact that they will always encounter the same environment, even throughout different models of a system, and can do extreme optimizations for the hardware they run on that are usually not feasible on a PC.

It's also not a "new" property of consoles in any way: there also were different models of the Super NES, for example. One reason why manufacturers do different models is because they thrive to make production cheaper and thus increase margins and/or make the system cheaper for customers.

There are few exceptions to this: for example, some consoles support additional hardware and there are models that then have the additional hardware already integrated. There were numerous models of the [Sega MegaDrive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sega_Genesis#Variations) (Genesis in the US) and it supported a CD drive add-on (it did more than just provide the drive, though). There then was a model that integrated the MegaDrive and the CD drive add-on into a single case. Another interesting example of violating the "equal hardware" assumption is the Nintendo N64, where you could [upgrade the RAM from 4MB to 8MB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nintendo_64_accessories#Expansion_Pak).

Comment: The 2nd part of this answer is especially informative. Not that it applies to any modern consoles (that I'm aware of), but I believe certain N64 games would require the additional RAM. If my memory serves me correctly, Majora's Mask and Donkey Kong 64 required the expansion pack.

Comment: Launch Super NES consoles would sometimes crash when using DMA for memcpy and for raster effects at the same time. It was fixed in version 2 of the CPU, but games had to work around it when running on version 1 consoles. Some of these workarounds caused occasional slowdown. Also there were "blue" and "green" variants of the original PlayStation chipset with slightly different bugs, and games had to run well on both.

Comment: This works good ellaborating off the original answer.. but if yoir ellaborating, it should be a comment. Not a seperate answer. Its also worth noting that the RAM upgrade for the nintendo 64 was only used on a few titles. The biggest one was donkey kong 64, which due to a bungle, ended up including the ram upgrade for free, anyway

Comment: @Timelord64 don't forget the greatest shooter of the generation, Perfect Dark

Comment: Too right,@Dallium. What I should have said was that the expansion pack was most notabley obtained with the Donkey Kong game, which was out shortly before perfect dark.

Answer (score 0):

Lol this is a kind of a hilarious question. Why so many upvotes? Apparently game developers will keep the hardware capacity of those devices in mind when they're developing games, and the games they publish will run totally fine on the target platform, otherwise it'd be a fail on their side.

The only case when you need to "upgrade" is when the next-gen console comes out, i.e. PS4 and XBox One. In such cases new games will be published in the new platforms, and those games will most likely not support the old platform at all. However such an upgrade cycle will likely be significantly longer than a typical PC upgrade cycle.

Of course you might argue that the same game might run with better graphics on newer PC hardware compared with console which has been there for several years. However IMO gaming console graphic quality is good enough for most eyes. Also you'd have to consider that since consoles are dedicated to gaming, serious optimizations are in effect and they'll be much more efficient than PCs with similar hardware specs.